# Android ValueAnimator not working on some devices

Tags: android, animation, animator

On some devices when I use [**ValueAnimator**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator) the listener [**AnimatorUpdateListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener) is called only two times, below is the code how I initialize the value animator object.

```
val animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f).apply {
    addUpdateListener { animation ->
          Log.i("test", "${animation.animatedValue as Float}")
    }
    interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    duration = 4000
    start()
}
```

On most devices I get the Log messages : **0.0, 0.001, 0.0015,.... 1.0**, but on some device (Lenovo L38043) I get only two Log messages: **0.0, 1.0** so basically its called on the first and last values any idea why? Even if I change the initialization to **val animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 0.5f, 1f)** it still gets called only two times!

Even if I use integer values, I still get the same result. Below is the code for integer values

```
val animator = android.animation.ValueAnimator() .apply {
     setObjectValues(0, 100)
     addUpdateListener { animation ->
          Log.i("test", "${animation.animatedValue as Int}")
     }
     interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
     duration = 4000
     start()
}
```

On most devices I get Log messages **0,1,2,3...100**, but on some devices I get **0,100**.

Comment: Strange. Not sure but please check the phone is not on battery saver mode.

Comment: Is the animation really takes 4 seconds? I mean 0.0 printed on start then 1.0 4 seconds later?

Comment: No both calls are made immediately at the same time.

Comment: Looks like the OS scales the duration by 0 - see if your animation scaling is 1x in developer options

Comment: Yes the animation scaling was disabled, and after I change it to 1x it started working. So is that cause by the Developer Options when you enable it or all Lenovo L38043 phones have the same problem?

Comment: I believe it’s either this or batter saver regardless of what device runs your app.

Answer (score 3):

When user turn off animation in Setting, value Animator didn't work .
in Samsung s22 (Android 13) this is a radio button with Remove Animation label

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know about this feature before your comment.